# How can I render a SCNScene to a texture

Tags: opengl, scenekit

I need to render a secondary SCNScene into a texture (NSImage) in the background to have that scene available as texture in the "main" SCNScene. I tried to use a new SCNView (which is not added to a superview) in conjunction with the secondary scene and its snapshot() method but it either draws the scene only partially or not at all. It actually seems to have a "timing issue". If I add a sleep between assigning the scene to the SCNView and the snapshot() call, it renders completely. If I have them directly executed after each other, the scene is only rendered partially.
I tried the various other proposals that I found here in similar articles (i.e renderToImage as extension of SCNRenderer) but they all show the same timing issue.
What would be the right way to render a secondary scene into a NSImage (while the primary scene is displayed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see links to the other proposals you're talking about, but `SCNRenderer` should be able to help you here — the `renderAtTime:` method lets you choose the scene timestamp at which to render, so you should be able to make that use the same timestamp as the current frame.

You might also be able to improve performance by skipping the `NSImage` step — which requires reading back data from the GPU to create an image in CPU memory, then feeding it back to the GPU. Possibly you can have your `SCNRenderer` target an `NSOpenGLLayer` or `MTLTexture`, which you can then set as your material's diffuse content to reuse the rendering surface directly.

Finally, you can use `SK3DNode` to display SceneKit (3D) content in a SpriteKit (2D) scene... and you can texture map an `SKScene` onto a SceneKit 3D object by setting it as a material property's contents. I'm not sure how that'll work for your animation sync issues, but it should at least keep everything in the same render surface.

Comment: Just for fun, I idid a quick implementation of the SK3DNode approach: 2 rotating cubes, each of which has 3 SpriteKit scenes, each of which plays the famous spinning ship animation. They stay in sync just fine. Two notes: first, move the SK3DNode to the center of the SpriteKit scene. Second, flip the y-axis of the SceneKit camera for the embedded scene (I'm not thrilled with the way I'm doing it but it works). Source at https://github.com/halmueller/ImmersiveInterfaces in the "Nested Scenes" folder.

Comment: Presumably you're flipping the camera because the texture mapped scene is upside down? That's an effect of the difference between texture coordinates and SpriteKit scene coordinates, so it probably makes the most sense to handle it at the texture mapping level — use `contentsTransform` and a scale matrix that inverts y.

Comment: Yep! I kicked around a few different transforms and scale changes  (at material level, SK3DNode level, and camera), and managed to achieve a black screen. I'll leave it alone for now, but PR's are welcome!

Comment: I tried the SK3DNode and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much. I spent half a day on all kinds of tries to render to a GL context (which continued to have timing issues with partial rendering) and all I had to do was to wrap the scene in the Sk3DNode. I just never came to the idea to search on the SceneKit side... Thanks again!